# Combine images using a nightshade

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Hi python and data visualization gurus,

I want to use the `m.bluemarble()` image as my "day" image, but then I want to use a different `m.warpimage(...)` as my "night" image.

Like this: [image]

I am wondering if I can somehow use the `m.nightshade()`, but instead of just a black color, have it reveal the `m.warpimage` product instead?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12,8))
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='l', 
            area_thresh=None, ax=axes)
m.bluemarble()
m.warpimage('http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/55000/55167/earth_lights_lrg.jpg')
m.nightshade(datetime.utcnow(), alpha=0.5)
m.scatter([-75, 30, 40, 50, 60], [40, 20, 15, 10, -5], color='red', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

So, this almost does what I want, but it overwrites the original blue marble, which is not what I want to have happen. In the output image, where the image is darker (by the `nightshade` call), I want the `warpimage` to show through, but everywhere else, I want the original `bluemarble`.

Does anyone know a simple way to do this? Or, conversely, the hard way to do it, and still have a cool output image? For science.

Thanks in advance! Any advice is welcomed. I'm having a mental road-block...

Jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise this is an old post, but as I was looking to do a similar thing I thought I'd post my possible solution. I'm a recent newcomer to Python so forgive the coding. I'm sure it can be tidied/rewritten more efficiently or using a more appropriate method!

From my Jupyter-Notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib import path
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

def bluemarble_daynight(date,scale):

    # Define Bluemarble and Nightshade objects
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12,8))
    m  = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution= None,
                 area_thresh=None, ax=axes)
    bm = m.bluemarble(scale=scale)
    ns = m.nightshade(date, alpha=0.5)

    bm_rgb = bm.get_array()
    bm_ext = bm.get_extent()

    axes.cla()

    # Get the x and y index spacing
    x = np.linspace(bm_ext[0], bm_ext[1], bm_rgb.shape[1])
    y = np.linspace(bm_ext[2], bm_ext[3], bm_rgb.shape[0])

    # Define coordinates of the Bluemarble image
    x3d,y3d = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    pts     = np.hstack((x3d.flatten()[:,np.newaxis],y3d.flatten()[:,np.newaxis]))

    # Find which coordinates fall in Nightshade 
    # The following could be tidied up as there should only ever one polygon. Although
    # the length of ns.collections is 3? I'm sure there's a better way to do this.
    paths, polygons = [], []
    for i, polygons in enumerate(ns.collections):
        for j, paths in enumerate(polygons.get_paths()):
            #print j, i
            msk = paths.contains_points(pts)

    # Redefine mask
    msk        = np.reshape(msk,bm_rgb[:,:,0].shape)
    msk_s      = np.zeros(msk.shape)
    msk_s[~msk] = 1.

    # Smooth interface between Night and Day
    for s in range(bm_rgb.shape[1]/50): # Make smoothing between day and night a function of Bluemarble resolution
        msk_s = 0.25 * (  np.vstack( (msk_s[-1,:            ], msk_s[:-1, :            ]) )  \
                        + np.vstack( (msk_s[1:,:            ], msk_s[0  , :            ]) )  \
                        + np.hstack( (msk_s[: ,0, np.newaxis], msk_s[:  , :-1          ]) )  \
                        + np.hstack( (msk_s[: ,1:           ], msk_s[:  , -1,np.newaxis]) ) )

    # Define new RGBA array
    bm_rgba = np.dstack((bm_rgb, msk_s))

    # Plot up Bluemarble Nightshade
    m    = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution= None, 
                   area_thresh=None, ax=axes)
    bm_n = m.warpimage('http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/55000/55167/earth_lights_lrg.jpg',scale=scale)
    bm_d = m.imshow(bm_rgba)
    plt.title('Day/Night Map for %s (UTC)' % date.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))
    plt.show()

date = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0)
bluemarble_daynight(date,0.25)
```

[image: Bluemarble day/night plot]

Comment: I think it's perfect. Really awesome and concise, actually. Thanks!